# Proper Laravel routing with absence of URI parameters

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.5

I have a form which can be saved as draft. The initial route will not have the parameter with the submitted id -- since it has not been submitted. Once it's saved, the route will contain the submitted id to retrieve the data and show it to the user.

I am currently creating multiple routes to accommodate this, which is very messy and can see how this will be an issue to maintain.

How can I account for the absence of parameters in routes, especially the form routes or controllers which throw an error with missing variables?

Routes:

```
Route::get('/request/{unit}/{id}',
   'RequestsController@showNewRequest')->name('request.show-new-request');

Route::get('/request/{unit}/{id}/{rid}',
   'RequestsController@showRequest')->name('request.show-request');

Route::post('/request/{unit}/{id}',
   'RequestsController@storeNew')->name('request.store-new');

Route::post('/request/{unit}/{id}/{rid}',
   'RequestsController@store')->name('request.store');
```

Controllers

```
public function showNewRequest($unit, $id) { }

public function showRequest($unit, $id, $rid) { }
```

Form/Blade:

```
@if(isset($rid))
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
    action="{{ route('request.store', ['unit' => $unit, 'id' =>  $id, 'rid' =>  $rid]) }}">
@else
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
    action="{{ route('request.store-new', ['unit' => $unit, 'id' =>  $id]) }}">
@endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `?` in the route parameters. This will let you ignore them. Then you can change the code to something like this:

```
Route::get('/request/{unit}/{id}/{rid?}',
   'RequestsController@showRequest')->name('request.show-request');
```

Controller:

```
public function showRequest($unit, $id, $rid = null) {
    if ($rid) {
        //Do something with $rid
    } else {
        //Do something considering that this is a draft.
    }
}
```

This also applies to post routes.